# Difference between object routes and RouteValueDictionary routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just wanted to understand the difference between below two overloads of RedirectToAction method-

```
RedirectToAction(String actionMethod, Object routes)

RedirectToAction(String actionMethod, RouteValueDictionary routes)
```

I think practically they both looks to be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, the method transforms the anonymous object into `RouteValueDictionary` so the first overload is just a convenience method.

See [Source](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L484)